# What does this chance mean in the context?

Tags: expressions

The sentence is:

> Being single is better than **chancing** a broken heart.

Answer (score 1):

> Being single is better than **chancing** a broken heart.

means the same as:

> Being single is better than **taking a chance on** a broken heart.

Comment: .. or risking a broken heart?

Comment: How do you figure out ?